# Starting Producer-Tasks from called Method?

Tags: c#, task, producer-consumer

I am kinda new in Tasks and have to solve a problem here. I am constantly getting an int and a float (approx. every 10ms), which are originally filtered from a constant data stream, then processed by different algorithms. I want to stack them into a BlockingCollection to have a ConsumerProducer pattern for my further processing of these data. I want to start several Producers and Consumer but I am stuck here, as I dont know how to handle these constant data stream. My approach is like:

```
public void Store(int iChannel, float fValue)
{
    producer = new Task(() => { BundleAndPutOnMyBlockingCollection(iChannel, fValue);
}
```

...it is obvious that this gives me loads of tasks, as Store() is continuously called. I tried with mytask.status to do the handling but failed. Can someone give me a hint how to handle this problem? Best would be to have a scaleable number of tasks for producing, e.g. 100 to test with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're never *starting* the tasks, so nothing will ever end up in the blocking collection this way... but it's not really clear to me why you'd want a task here at all. Why doesn't your `Store` method just add it to the blocking collection directly? You may well want a task for the *consumer*, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the .Start() at the above line, this one must have come from another try where I was executing the task somewhere else. Okay, so I gonna just use one producer -- I was thinking somehow that this wont be anough to handle the rapid input. Thanks, I gonna try that.

Comment: @Rome: Why wouldn't it be enough to handle the rapid input? You're only adding to a collection - you're not waiting for the whole collection to be processed. If you're worried that you may end up filling up your blocking collection (assuming it's bounded) then starting a task really isn't going to help you - if you're producing data faster than you can consume it, you're going to have to either back off or lose data. That's a decision we can't really help you with.